# TFS 2013 only execute impacted tests

Tags: c#, automated-tests

I'm having an extremely hard time determining how to only execute impacted tests in TFS 2013.

I've tried following every single example of using the methods described for TFS 2010 and 2012 to obtain a list of Impacted tests using the GetImpactedTests build activity but for some reason I can't for the life of me get it to recognize the reference to the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client assembly.

It resolves every other assembly except for this one and it's when I create a variable of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.BuildIntegration.BuildActivities.TestList and use it with the GetImpactedTests build activity.

For some reason it can't find the reference to the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.Test class.

It makes no sense why this doesn't want to work. The references are all in the project with the XAML. References Screenshot:

[image]

The concept I'm following is described at [Only Run Impacted Tests](http://blog.robmaherconsulting.co.nz/2011/03/tfs-2010-build-only-run-impacted-tests.html)

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What exact error did you get? Under which step did you get error?

Comment: Where assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client locates on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client version=**12.0.0.0** locates, and reference to correct path. Try to install [TFS Object Model installer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6) on your machine.

Comment: I put this on hold temporarily due to time constraints. One question I have is how would you share the test impact data from a nightly build running all of the tests with the the gated checkin build that I want to only run tests being impacted by code change when each build definition writes output under it's own folder on the build agent?